# Scanner#close() invocation before class instance garbage-collected?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I need to write a class with Iterator that iterates over file and returns one line of the file each time `Iterator#next()` is invoked. The problem is that I don't know when the reference of the Iterator instance will become unreachable (and maybe `garbage-collected` some time after), so I cannot invoke `Scanner#close()`.

So the question is, if there is any way to invoke `Scanner#close()` after reference of Iterator instance becomes unreachable but before it is garbage-collected?

```
public class FileWrapper implements Iterable<String> {

    private File file;

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
            return new Itr();
    }

    private class Itr implements Iterator<String> {

        private Scanner scanner;

        public Itr() {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return scanner.hasNextLine();
        }

        @Override
        public String next() {
            return scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try adding it in `finalize` method of `Itr` class (unless I misunderstood something). You can also make your `Itr` `Closeable` and let it be closed by user (or try-with-resources).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the `Closeable` approach if you can do so, because it is deterministic.

You could override `finalize`, but this is very problematic. There is no guarantee that `finalize` will ever get called. Finalizers also impose a penalty on the garbage collector. Don't mess with the finalization process if you can find a way to avoid it.

Also, note that this cleanup will be pinned to memory. You might run out of file handles long before you run out of memory. This makes deterministic cleanup of non-memory resources a much better option.

There is a third approach, which is to use a phantom reference.

```
public class FileWrapper implements Iterable<String> {

    private File file;
    // Keep track of phantom references to iterators
    private static ReferenceQueue<Itr> references = new ReferenceQueue<>();
    static {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    // Block until an iterator is about to be annihilated
                    Reference<Itr> ref = references.remove();
                    Itr aboutToDie = ref.get();
                    try {
                        aboutToDie.scanner.close();
                    }
                    catch(IOException ex) {
                        // Already closed?
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return new Itr();
    }

    private class Itr implements Iterator<String> {

        private Scanner scanner;

        public Itr() throws FileNotFoundException {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
            synchronized(references) {
                new PhantomReference(scanner, references);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return scanner.hasNextLine();
        }

        @Override
        public String next() {
            return scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Phantom references are kind of cool. Unlike strong or weak references, which have an affect on referent reachability and availability to be collected, phantom references have no hold on the referent at all. When all the strong or weak references go away and the referent has been finalized, the phantom reference is all that's left before ultimate annihilation.

At this point, the phantom reference will be added to the reference queue, where it will be available for you to pick up to perform pre-mortem processing.

Note: Google Collections has [FinalizablePhantomReference](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/FinalizablePhantomReference.html) that manages the background thread for you.

Comment: The “availability to be collected” is exactly the same for weak and phantom references. It’s not clear what difference you assume to exist between the two. Besides that 1) when you don’t keep a reference to the `PhantomReference`, it will get garbage collected with no effect 2) You are creating a reference to the `Scanner` but try to retrieve an `Itr` from it 3) Retrieving the referent doesn’t work anyway, as that’s the point of it; it doesn’t prevent garbage collection, so `get()` on enqueued references returns `null`, in case of `PhantomReference` it will return `null` even before enqueued.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution would be to make the `Iterator` implement `Closeable` as well, and make it the responsibility of the caller of `iterator()` to call `close()`.  The closeable iterator's `close()` method would close the `Scanner`.

Unfortunately, shoehorning that into a context where the the iterator's lifecycle is managed via the `Iterable` / `Iterator` APIs ..... would be problematic.  Certainly, you wouldn't be able to get

```
 for (String s : someFileWrapper) {
      ....
 }
```

to close the `Iterator` at the end of the loop.

If you made `Itr` implement `AutoCloseable` as well as `Iterator` and gave up on using the "for each" style `for` loop, you could use a "try with resources" to manage the lifecycle.  But it is cumbersome.

---

Another possible solution would be to take responsibility for the file descriptor lifecycle away from the `FileWrapper`; e.g. make it a `ScannerWrapper` instead, and make the lifecycle the responsibility of whatever creates / manages that object.  (However, that fundamentally changes the semantics of the wrapper.  The wrapper can only be used to generate an iterator once.)

---

The suggested `finalize` approach doesn't actually achieve anything.  The issue is that the `FileInputStream` inside the `Scanner` will become garbage at the same time that the `Scanner` and the `FileWrapper.Itr` instance do.   `FileInputStream` already has a `finalize()` method that will call `close()`.